# Why are the seeds different when going from seed to mnemonic and back using bx?

Tags: seed, mnemonic-seed

From an example in the [documentation](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-mnemonic-to-seed):

```
$ bx seed | bx mnemonic-new | bx mnemonic-to-seed | bx hd-new
```

`655a1ed2d4fef69bb314198c7327f23c
grab special regret prepare urge evidence slush lobster midnight odor wish ketchup
57bae342ae8e69eb63f17ef993a90a59159e0f78114b602bf0ebabfec0e5d086e883c31975bf03f8a47a32853452623094d1303fd0549745db457145e5756582
xprv9s21ZrQH143K43CUCgNp5SmXzg2axQx2P4WupA2zEnKpFM19QfqfdqfpJR3yfzAXZnsHeUaQhWQMwyuqL8DbdeLeCbdMoKNn6pCY4RUn2pK`

In Mastering Bitcoin, the example given [here](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/appdx-bx.asciidoc) shows it going back to the seed that was originally created; this was done using an older version of bx though. Can someone explain how the seeds from line 1 and line 3 in the example are encoded/related?

Comment: Warning: `bx seed` generates insecure seeds from [a pseudorandom number generator and very low entropy.](https://milksad.info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They adopted bip39 where the seed mnemonic is [run through a key derivation function](https://github.com/trezor/python-mnemonic/blob/master/mnemonic/mnemonic.py#L184) to derive the seed. This is an irreversible step.

Comment: answering the wrong question, overloading the term "seed" is too common

Answer (score 1):

Fundamental flaw here, multiple meanings of the word "seed"even within discussion of just BIP39.

The "entropy" is a better term for the BIP39 starting point. Then the endpoint of the process should be "BIP39 numeric seed".

> "Convert the entropy to a BIP39 mnemonic. Use that mnemonic plus a (technically optional but no) passphrase as the inputs to produce the BIP39 numeric seed. End of BIP39. "

is how I would tell the story.

Now, looking at this from *Mastering Bitcoin *

> The seed can be encoded using the mnemonic-encode command:

> $ bx hd-mnemonic < seed > words
> adore repeat vision worst especially veil inch woman cast recall dwell appreciate

> The seed can then be decoded using the mnemonic-decode command:

> $ bx mnemonic-decode < words
> eb68ee9f3df6bd4441a9feadec179ff1

Andreas Antonopoulos is here clearly using "seed" to refer to the entropy. The process described does not involve hashing, or cryptographic "encoding", it's just a change in representation, like going from binary to hex.

Except for the N/32 checksum getting added.

Which means an input entropy of 256 bits is entirely reversible, but the last 8 bits to get to 264 (24 words x 11 bits) is the result of the checksum process.

What the other answers here are referring to is not the "entropy seed" but the output, the "BIP39 numeric seed" which is indeed a one way derivation process.

I believe the `bx mnemonic-decode` command may have gotten removed simply because it is useless, or at least I cannot think of a use case.

I do not think it stopped working in the transition to BIP39. **EDIT** The entropy to mnemonic "conversion" is reversed by many tools - see https://iancoleman.app

Comment: Yes the entropy and mnemonic "encoding" process is fully reversible http://www.petecorey.com/blog/2018/05/07/reversing-bip39-and-the-power-of-property-testing

Comment: Also with https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39

Answer (score 1):

A note for those reading this in the future: "bx seed" is completely insecure and will result in your money being stolen.  See [CVE-2023-39910](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2023-39910), aka the "Milk Sad" issue:

> The use of an mt19937 Mersenne Twister PRNG restricts the internal
> entropy to 32 bits regardless of settings. This allows remote
> attackers to recover any wallet private keys generated from "bx seed"
> entropy output and steal funds. (Affected users need to move funds to
> a secure new cryptocurrency wallet.)

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same questions regarding the example in Mastering Bitcoin and here is the answer:

> The old mnemonic-decode (electrum v1 mnemonics I believe) was dropped
>   from libbitcoin before version3 and replaced with BIP-39 mnemonics.
>   libbitcoin version4 also adds in electrum v2 mnemonics. Unlike
>   electrum v1 mnemonics (which are symmetric), BIP-39 is asymmetric
>   --https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/issues/366

Comment: asking the wrong question, overloading the term "seed" is too common